# Rebus Send method doesn't throw an exception when queue doesn't exist

Tags: rebus

I noticed that Send(TCommand) method doesn't throw an exception if queue doesn't exist. I wanted to ask is it desired behaviour?

In the output I can see first chance exceptions though, but I can't find place where it is handled in Rebus code.

Also I believe it doesn't create missing queue for some good reasons, am I right? :)

Wouldn't it be nice to also throw exception if destination queue is not transactional?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're saying "transactional" about a queue, I'm assuming that you're using MSMQ.

With MSMQ, you'll get an exception if the destination queue does not exist *only when the queue is local* - if the queue is on another machine, that simply cannot happen, because messages destined for other machines are put in a local *outgoing* queue.

In fact, you can send to *any queue on machines that don't exist*, and you'll get no error - the message will end up stored in an outgoing queue on the local machine. After a while, MSMQ will give up trying to deliver the message, and it will be moved to the dead-letter queue where it will be safely stored until you delete it (or send it somewhere else, using e.g. [Rebus Snoop](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Snoop)).

When I tried to reproduce this issue with [this code](https://gist.github.com/mookid8000/fec9386fddb609b2ab31), I got the following result (as expected):

[image: result when sending to nonexistent queue]

Another thing: If the recipient queue is non-transactional, you'll experience no error when sending - *but the message (as always) is not lost!* - it's just residing in the transactional dead-letter queue, waiting for operations to understand that there is a problem:

[image: tx dead-letter queue]

IMO it doesn't make sense to check whether recipient queues are transactional since recipient queues do not belong to the sender and thus should not impose their problems on the sender.

Comment: oh, wow,  I can't stop wondering how little I still know about queues :) So to make beahviour constant it handles exception when local queue doesn't exist?

Comment: oh, no! when the destination queue is local, it should definitely throw an exception! if that is not the case, please let me know

Comment: yes, orginal question was for the local queue case. I use bus.Advanced.Routing.Send("NotExistingQueue", TCommand)

Comment: omg, I'm sorry for taking your time unceseccary :( The exception wasn't thrown because I was sending inside of Timer.Elased. Thank you for your effort

Comment: excellent! it's always good when you end up being able to explain why stuff works or doesn't :)

Comment: do you think checking if queue is transactional is not needed in case of Send? I mean when it is send without any error one could be surprised that nothing appeared in queue

Comment: I updated the answer :) and no, the sender should not have to worry about whether another queue has a problem, that is the other queue's (i.e. the _owner of the other queue_'s) problem